# How to render data to Pdf once you have binary data from server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, download

I have post request which i am sending data to server and in response i have binary data from server for pdf ,Once i call pdfExport i see the response and Pdf file download but when i open that file its blank i dont see the data in pdf file. Any idea what i am doing wrong in below code...

So far tried code...

mainCtrl.js

```
$scope.pdfExport = function(){
      var fileName = "test.pdf";
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      console.log("Pdf export..");
      RiskHomePageService.getPdfExport($scope.dashboardGrid.options).then(function(result){
        console.log("response server",result);
        var file = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'application/force-download'});
        console.log("after blob");
        var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        console.log("file data",file);
        a.href = fileURL;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
      });
    }
```

mainService.js

```
getPdfExport: function(data){
          return $http.post('/app/pdf/export',data).then(function(response){
            return response;
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that

```
return $http.post('/app/pdf/export',data,{responseType:'arraybuffer'})
```